# Ember Simple Auth & Ember Simple Auth Token

Tags: authentication, ember.js

I'm using ember simple-auth with ember simple-auth-token and I would like to take the value of the user's token in order to use it in an ajax call.
How can I access token value? I tried the following syntax:

```
 headers: {"Authorization":"Token" + " auth_token"}
```

and

```
 headers: {"Authorization":"Token" + " session.data"}
```

but none of them have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about simple-auth-token, but I am using ember-simple-auth and I am adding the token to each outgoing request extending a base authorizer as shown below:

```
// app/authorizers/my-own-authorizer.js

import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/base';

export default Base.extend({

  /**
   * Authorizes all outgoing requests by a session-token that has been received during a login process.
   * If such a session token does not exist, it does not add anything.
   * @override
   * @param {Object} sessionData received from the backend on a successful login
   * @param {Function} addHeaderFunction function that appends a custom header into the next request
     */
  authorize(sessionData, addHeaderFunction){
    const sessionToken = Ember.get(sessionData, "meta.session-token");
    if (Ember.isPresent(sessionToken)) {
      addHeaderFunction('authorization', sessionToken);
    }    
  }
});
```

Do not forget to adjust your application adapter so that it uses the authorizer:

```
// app/adapters/application.js
...
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
 ....
 authorizer: 'authorizer:my-own-authorizer',
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer but I was searching for something more simple. I finally found that I can access the token by calling self.get("session.data.authenticated.auth_token").

Comment: I used to do the same but docs explicitly talk about extending authorizer and overriding the `authorize()` function. I find the code more readable now as I don't have to mix concerns where they do not belong to.

Comment: With ember-simple-auth-token I have only needed to use the DataAdapterMixin. Everything else was handled automatically for me ...

Comment: You really should use an `authorizer` for this!